# Is there any way to log logs in file in GAE GWT application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, logging, log4j

I am new to GAE GWT Application. I am developing a GAE - GWT application with spring MVC 3 as service provider and GWT as UI client (I am not comfortable using GWT's RPC concept, so I started using spring) and log4j (v1.2.17) & log4j-gwt-1.0` for logging. Now I need to log the "logs" in a file.

But when coding, it seems, GWT accepts `ConsoleAppender` but not `FileAppender` or `RollingFileAppender`.

How to configure log4j in GWT to log the "(server)logs" in a separate file?

My log4j.properties file

```
# A default log4j configuration for log4j users.
#
# To use this configuration, deploy it into your application's WEB-INF/classes
# directory.  You are also encouraged to edit it as you like.

# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1

# Configure the console as our one appender
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] - %m%n
log4j.appender.A1.File=/logger.log
log4j.appender.A1.MaxFileSize=10MB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.A1.MaxBackupIndex=1


# tighten logging on the DataNucleus Categories
log4j.category.DataNucleus.JDO=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Persistence=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Cache=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.MetaData=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.General=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Utility=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Transaction=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Datastore=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.ClassLoading=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Plugin=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.ValueGeneration=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Enhancer=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.SchemaTool=WARN, A1
```

and My code snippet.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
final private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("RegistrationController");
```

Exception :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.FileOutputStream is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.RuntimeHelper.checkRestricted(RuntimeHelper.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkRestricted(Runtime.java:64)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:262)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:127)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:135)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1025)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:844)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:671)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.<clinit>(DispatcherServlet.java:246)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:249)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:306)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:79)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:88)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$2.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:383)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$2.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:376)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restart(DevAppServerImpl.java:376)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher$AppEngineServletContainer.refresh(AppEngineLauncher.java:51)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.onRestartServer(DevMode.java:349)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.RemoteUI.restartWebServer(RemoteUI.java:166)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.DevModeServiceRequestProcessor.processRestartServer(DevModeServiceRequestProcessor.java:94)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.DevModeServiceRequestProcessor.execute(DevModeServiceRequestProcessor.java:59)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.MessageTransport.processClientRequest(MessageTransport.java:362)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.MessageTransport.processMessage(MessageTransport.java:404)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.MessageTransport.access$400(MessageTransport.java:44)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.MessageTransport$3.run(MessageTransport.java:322)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet).
```

Is there any way to log the logs in a file instead of console?
If not, how to get the console logs, once it is deployed in GAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me you have bigger problems then logging. First GWT and GAE are 2 different things. GWT is a tool kit to build JavaScript applications in Java, and GAE is a server side framework. So when you say `I am not comfortable using GWT's RPC concept, so I started using spring` It looks to me as if you don't completely understand what's going on. Spring runs on the server and a GWT application in the browser. To communicate between the browser and the server GWT has among other things RPC for this, which takes care of the communication between the browser and server. Spring runs only on the server, and thus won't help you with communicating between your GWT application in the browser and the server. So your comment sounds like a red flag to me.

So to continue on the logging. There are 2 sides of this story.

First logging on the server, or in GAE. GAE has it's own build in logging. See (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/?csw=1#Java_Logging). The short answer here is when using log4j you need to configure it to log to stdout and stderr. There are several questions here on stackoverflow regarding how to configure this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine+log4j).

Second, if you want to see GWT logs once deployed, technical it means, you send the logging from the browser back to the server and then on the server get them in the standard logging of the server. Fortunately GWT has support for this out of the box, all you need to do is enable remote logging. Add the following line in your gwt.xml file:

```
<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED" />
```

For more on GWT logging and remote logging see: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Remote_Logging